# Is there a full list of Ukrainian words with the letter Ґ ґ?

Tags: orthography, приголосні, абетка

According to [Ukrainian Orthography 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2015.htm)

> § 15. Літера Ґ
>
> Літера ґ передає на письмі задньоязиковий зімкнений приголосний як в
>   українських словах, так і в давнозапозичених і зукраїнізованих: аґрус,
>   ґава, ґазда, ґандж, ґанок, ґатунок, ґвалт, ґвалтувати, ґеґати, ґедзь,
>   ґелґотати, ґерґотати, ґерґотіти, ґиґнути, ґирлиґа, ґлей, ґніт (у
>   лампі), ґоґель-моґель, ґрасувати, ґрати (іменник), ґратчастий,
>   ґречний, ґринджоли, ґрунт, ґудзик, ґуля, джиґун, дзиґа, дзиґлик тощо
>   та похідні від них, а також у прізвищах Ґалаґан, Ґудзь і под.
>
> Примітка. У власних назвах іншомовного походження етимологічний g
>   згідно з усталеною традицією вимовляється як г; проте збереження g у
>   вимові не є порушенням орфоепічної норми. Отже, правильною є вимова:
>   Гданськ і Ґданськ, Гренландія й Ґренландія, Гібралтар і Ґібралтар;
>   Гарібальді й Ґарібальді, Гете й Ґете. /20/

Should we consider the list above as the exhaustive (complete) one (`тощо` remark challenges certain doubts) or is there any other more comprehensive list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are definitely much more words with the letter `ґ`, but the list depends on its author. I prefer using [Borys Hrinchenko's](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%B7_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8E_%D2%90_%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) list in this case.

There is also a useful [list of rules](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D2%90) explaining how to use this letter.

Comment: thank you. It's interesting. But a consequent question is on the way - will it be considered a mistake if one writes or types such words with ordinary Г instead Ґ, e.g. автобіоґрафія, автоґраф, аґент  - under [Borys Hrinchenko dictionary list](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%B7_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8E_%D2%90_%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) ?

Comment: Due to we don't currently have single list of rules for it and multiple definitions of usage (one is above) it can't be treated as a mistake. Thanks for good question by the way.

Answer (score -1):

The letter 'ґ' is the Ukrainian equivalent to the English letter 'g.'  Asking for a full list of words is like asking for that whole section of the dictionary.

As far as is it a mistake to use a 'ґ' in the place of a 'г.' A 'г' is the Ukrainian equivalent of an 'h.'  You're basically asking if it's a mistake to use a 'g' in the place of an 'h.'  At best it would make your writing somewhat unintelligible.

Just for fun:

*Tge letter 'ґ' is tge Ukrainian equivalent to tge Enhlisg letter 'h.'  Askinh for a full list of words is like askinh for tgat wgole section of tge dictionary.

As far as is it a mistake to use a 'ґ' in tge place of a 'г.' A 'г' is tge Ukrainian equivalent of an 'g.'  You're basically askinh if it's a mistake to use a 'h' in tge place of an 'g.'  At best it would make your writinh somewgat unintellihible.*

Comment: Welcome to Ukrainian Language.SE! Although this post contains a nice example of how funny it looks when people replace one consonant with another, it seems that the original question asked whether there are more words with the `ґ` (i.e., whether the quoted list is complete), and this post does not address this.