# Is the letter Ґ back?

Tags: non-native-speaker

It has come to my attention that the letter Ґ, once banned from the Ukrainian alphabet,
is coming back into favor in words like ґудзик and ґазета.  Is this so, and are there other words where Ґ has been reintroduced in common usage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a full list of Ukrainian words with the letter Ґ ґ?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/462/is-there-a-full-list-of-ukrainian-words-with-the-letter-%d2%90-%d2%91)

Comment: Maybe you can find some answers here: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6532/3173 (in Ukrainian)